# Android - Making Webview DomStorage persistant after app closed

Tags: android, webview, local-storage, persistent

I'm facing a huge problem developing an Android app which use a Webview to display datas. The website i'm using in the webview use localStorage API of HTML 5.

To enable this feature i've set the webview setting like this :

```
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

So the localStorage API works but when I close the app (and kill the process), localStorage is completly erased and when I reload it, all my datas are lost.

My question is simple : How to make DomStorage of a Webview persistant even when we close the app ?

Thank you for all you future answers.

Comment: I've found the solution, you need to set the databasePath in order to save datas :
webview.getSettings().setDatabasePath();

Comment: Can you share what the path you set it to? I am facing the same problem now.

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Is it possible to read the local storage vars that are set by the html5 directly from java?  I've found the question asked elsewhere, but no one seems to have an answer?

Answer (score 10):

Did you set the DatabasePath? Android doesn't know where to save the DOMDatabase by default, if you don't set it calling

```
webview.getSettings().setDatabasePath()
```

Comment: note you can only call setDatabase path once - subsequent calls are ignored.  You need to terminate the application to force WebKit to reload (calling Activity.finish() will not guarantee this) before any subsequent calls take affect

Answer (score 10):

```
// Confimed on android 2.1 emulator
// enable javascript localStorage

WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);   // localStorage

// e.g., if your package is www.myapp.whatever;
webSettings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/www.myapp.whatever/databases/");
```

Comment: what about in andorid 2.2 , whether its working or not, because for me in 2.1 its working but not in 2.2

Comment: If you are having "setDatabasePath deprecated" error with this usage, in chromium webkit browser handles the path itself. [See this answer for more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319279/android-webview-setdatabasepath-deprecated)

Answer (score 7):

You must enable the database as well as setting its path:

```
webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDatabasePath();
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

The first line caught me out for quite a while...

Answer (score 0):

The above post is mixing two diferent concepts:

To make your data persist after the session is closed make sure you are not using (on your javascript) sessionStorage

DOMStorage and database storage are two different things. Database storage is not part of HTML5: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

DOMStorage is more related to HTML5 and includes session storage, which -by design- will disappear when you close your browser. You will find more hits via searching "local storage' that 'DOM storage'.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/introduction-html5-domstorage-api-example/

Thus, to enable DOMstorage you just need this:
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

This issue was answered [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19631055/1166441) with an update for Android v4.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
```

That is all you need for the latest APIs. The database path is managed automatically by chrome