# Android WebView throws SQLiteException

Tags: android, sqlite, android-webview

I am getting crash reports from sporadic `SQLiteException`s in my application. I am not directly interacting with SQLite databases at all. I have tracked the code down to the usage of the `WebView` widget. The exceptions differ in cause, but a couple of examples are as follows...

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: database is locked: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1768)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransactionWithListener(SQLiteDatabase.java:558)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:512)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.startCacheTransaction(WebViewDatabase.java:603)
at android.webkit.CacheManager.enableTransaction(CacheManager.java:251)
at android.webkit.WebViewWorker.handleMessage(WebViewWorker.java:214)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Another example...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.example.MyApplication: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "VALUES": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO cache (VALUES (
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3828)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1082)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "VALUES": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO cache (VALUES (
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1231)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils$InsertHelper.getStatement(DatabaseUtils.java:858)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils$InsertHelper.getColumnIndex(DatabaseUtils.java:904)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.getInstance(WebViewDatabase.java:397)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1077)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1054)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1044)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1035)
at com.example.MyApplication.getWebView(MyApplication.java:223)
at com.example.MyApplication.loadUrlInWebView(MyApplication.java:249)
at com.example.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:169)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:984)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3825)
... 10 more
```

Why might these crashes be occurring? Has anyone else had this problem?

**Note:** The platform in the error reports are each listed as **OTHER**, so maybe this is only happening in an emulator or unofficial build of the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to the webview DOM storage. See WebSettings.setDatabaseEnabled and WebSettings.setDatabasePath.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDatabaseEnabled(boolean)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDatabasePath(java.lang.String)

A common complaint is that the DOM storage does not work, and that is usually fixed with code like this:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/packagename/databases/");
```

I never heard of crash problems with this, but it may be worth investigating what happens when you disable DOM storage and when you specify a proper database path (as shown above using your app's packagename).

This thread may also be helpful:
[Android - Making Webview DomStorage persistant after app closed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4157184/483708)

Comment: This seems pretty likely to be the culprit. I'm not loading any HTML that takes advantage of the HTML5 data API anyway, so I wonder if I could just turn off DOM storage and database access altogether? I'd hate to hard-code a database path if I don't have to.