# How I do to localStorage no lost when I closed App Webview?

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a WebView Android, I'm using localStoage to save session but when I close app, localStorage lost, How I do to no lost my localStorage?

Comment: [Data Lost After Application Restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12052055/5791681)

Comment: @RicardoA.but setDatabasePath is was deprecated how i do now?

Comment: [android webview setDatabasePath deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319279/android-webview-setdatabasepath-deprecated)

Comment: @RicardoA. I got it, thanks very much