# Android Kotlin - Webview Database

Tags: android, database, kotlin, webview, android-webview

My webview is loading the url because it need database enabled.

I tried the code below.

it's working on devices higher then API 19
but android 4.4.4 not working for me

```
 webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            // webview.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
            //webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            webview.settings.setSupportZoom(false)
            webview.settings.builtInZoomControls = false
            webview.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
            webview.settings.databaseEnabled = true
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                val databasePath = getDatabasePath("yourDbName")
                webview.settings.setDatabasePath(databasePath.path)
                //webview.settings.databasePath = "/data/data/" + webview.context.packageName + "/databases/"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the Android developer documentations, this was deprecated in API 19

[check documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#getDatabasePath())

API level 19 means Android 4.4 KitKat, in which the browser engine is switched from Android webkit to chromium webkit, with almost all the original WebView APIs wrapped to the counterparts of chromium webkit.

That means most of the implementations of WebView APIs are different from Android 4.3 and before, incuding the database storage API. That also means since Android 4.4 developers cannot (or don't have to) assign an alternative db path; all this is handled by Android by default.

managed by the implementation now means the database storage path is handled by chromium webkit engine by default, while before Android 4.4 it's handled in android.webkit in framework layer which needs to be set.

For the original  answer, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21323063/7809502)