# Android Webview goback() issue with loadDataWithBaseURL method

Tags: android, webview

Issue is goback() not showing my html data back. Steps to produce this issue is like

1. Loaded html data using method loadDataWithBaseURL. It renders html data fine.
2. Then click on one link inside html data then webview moves to next page showing that link which is also fine.
3. When I call method goback() from this page it should show my html data but it is showing me blank screen. Inside onPageFinished() I am getting url as about:blank.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe through [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19631055/5885018) you find your way.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response statosdotcom. I have already enabled dom storage setting but issue is something else.

Comment: @VivekGabadiya Have you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you use **loadDataWithBaseURL** you will need to send in the url parameter something different from null, if you send null the url will always be "**about:blank**"

Example:

```
var page = new RazorView().GenerateString();
webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", page, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
var url = webView.CopyBackForwardList().GetItemAtIndex(1).Url; 
//url  will get the Html From Previous Page
```

Notice im using C# but it should be the same with java, except for the CapitalizedWords